# How to disable button if textbox is empty in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvmcross

I'm using wpf.MVVMC to create a wpf page, it contains a textbox and a button. If the textbox is empty, the next button should be disabled. But it didn't work.

xaml:

```
<TextBox Name="ServerName" Text="{Binding ServerName}" TextChanged="SqlServerNameTextbox_TextChanged"/>
<Button Command="{Binding NextCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsButtonEnabled}">Next</Button>
```

ViewModel:

```
public bool isButtonEnabled = true;
public bool IsButtonEnabled
{
    get => isButtonEnabled;
    set
    {
        isButtonEnabled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsButtonEnabled");

    }
}

public void HandleSqlNameTextChanged(string currentText)
{
    ServerName = currentText;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ServerName))
    {
        if (!NextCommand.CanExecute(null))
        {
            IsButtonEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}

public ICommand _nextCommand;
public virtual ICommand NextCommand
{
    get
    {

        if (_nextCommand == null)
        {

            _nextCommand = new DelegateCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    var controller = GetExactController();
                    controller.Next();
                },
                // can execute
                () => canGotoNext());
        }
        return _nextCommand;
    }
}

public virtual bool canGotoNext()
{
    if (!ValidateInputs())
    {
        IsButtonEnabled = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Do I miss anything? How to disable the button using command?
Thanks for your help.

Update:
The mix use of change event and Command is not recommended by official. If this issue could be reopened, I will post the right answers.

Comment: If your VM an INotifyPropertyChanged, and do you raise the property changed event when you set IsButtonEnabled? Can you post the IsButtonEnabled property code?

Comment: @Loocid thanks your reply, I did raise the property change event. Updated code

Comment: Your property and the binding look fine. I would put a breakpoint in the property setter to make sure it's actually being set when the textbox is empty. If it's not, that's your problem.

Comment: The property setter is called, but the button is not disabled. If I click next button when textbox is empty, the button could be disabled. Weird :(

Comment: Do not bind IsEnabled at all when you also bind the Command property. The enabled state is controlled by the ICommand source of the Command Binding.